# set header and footer in BlackBerry in VerticalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, footer

I searched how to set header and footer in BlackBerry and I found the functions `setTitle()` and `setStatus()`.

My problem is I have created a class that extends `VerticalFieldManager`. In `VerticalFieldManager`, it is not showing me `setStatus` function as this is function of `MainScreen` class.

Comment: will you show the code that you tried ?

Comment: Hi in class it is not showing me setStatus function. For this I created object of MyScreen class and use setStatus Function in following way.     MyScreen.footer.setStatus(bannerAd);

Comment: what is footer ?. If your class extending main screen, then use setStatus(youir_field);

Comment: @signare thanks for rply. The screen where i need to set footer is not extending MainScreen, it is extending VerticalFieldManager class. footer is object of MainScreen in MyScreen class. When i write above line gives me null pointer exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right.  A `VerticalFieldManager` does not allow you to `setStatus()` directly.

It's important to understand the relationship between the classes in the BlackBerry UI framework.

First of all, there are `Screen` classes.  Normally, a `Screen` will take up the entire device screen.  You can have many different `Screen` classes in your app.  Maybe one `Screen` for a splash image, one screen for a map view, one screen for settings, etc.

*Inside* your screens, you will often have `Manager` classes.  A `VerticalFieldManager` is a kind of `Manager` that arranges its contents top-to-bottom, in the order that you add them.  A `Manager` holds a group of related objects, but it does not have to span the full screen height, or width.

*Inside* your managers, you will usually have multiple `Field` objects.  A `Field` is the individual item in the heirarchy.  `ButtonField`, `EditField`, or `BrowserField` are all kinds of fields.  They will usually be added to managers (containers).  Those managers will then usually be added to screens.

So, in your case, I think what you should have is a screen class.  In that screen class, you will set the *header* and *footer* by calling `setTitle()` and `setStatus()`.  The content between the header and footer will all be contained in a `VerticalFieldManager` that you add to the screen.  Something like this:

```java
public class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

   public MyScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

      // set a header for this screen
      setTitle("My Header / Title");

      // screen contents go in the vertical field manager

      // NOTE:  you can replace VerticalFieldManager with your own class
      //   that extends Manager, or VerticalFieldManager, if you like
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();
      vfm.add(new LabelField("One"));
      vfm.add(new ButtonField("Two", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK));
      vfm.add(new CheckboxField("Three", true));

      add(vfm);

      // use a bitmap as a footer
      Bitmap footer = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("footer.png");
      setStatus(new BitmapField(footer));
   }
}
```